# WAMP Server Issues and Suggested Solutions

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have a working WAMP server with no problems on a Windows 8.1 Pro platform but i need to implement WAMP on several other machines all running a version of Windows (classroom environment). Some machines work perfectly fine, but others not so much. We are trying to reinstall WAMP but nothing seems to be working. The issue is

1.) every time i want to use WAMP i have to install all services before they can run. Then when i attempt to open a file on localhost i get an error that says service not found. Files are all in the right location (\www)

I have read that port 80 might be an issue but when we execute the port 80 test, no traffic issues. To be safe, we changed the port to 8080 and the same issues arrise.

Anybody have an issue like this or anything similar.

Comment: those operating system which does have this option enabled by default it would work, those which does not have this option enabled it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soluton above will probably aslo do the job. When I was dealing with the same issue with Wamp on Win 10. All resolved by following steps:

- open command line under as an administrator
- make sure it is process with PID 4 listening to port 80:

  netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80
- change http process to use another port (i.e. 8000):

  netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0:8000
- restart http service

  net stop http

  net start http
- restart Xamp processes

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem earlier, and the solution is

[image]

It should solve your problem.

Thanks